# What is the fastest way to test prime number i for ruby 2.2.0?

Tags: ruby, primes

**Fastest way to test prime number for ruby 2.2.0?**

```
def prime?
  ('1' * self) !~ /^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/
end
```

*I found this code somewhere but its not working properly someplaces*

Comment: *"its not working properly someplaces"* - please elaborate.

Comment: What is your question? How this code doesn't work, or what's the fasted way, those are two very different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [prime library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html).

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'prime'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Prime.prime?(2)
=> true
```

as @Stefan said, you can simply write

```
2.prime?
=> true
```

Comment: `Prime` patches `Integer`, so you can simply write `2.prime?`.